# pybind11: Enum vs Enum Class?

Tags: python, c++, enums, pybind11

I understand the difference between enums and enum classes in the context of C++, but in the context of binding enums and enum classes is there any real difference?

Say for example:

```
enum class options {
  maybe,
  yes,
  no,
};

enum words {
   hello,
   world
};
```

I've just been binding them the same way (see below), so my question is, am I overlooking something, or are enums and enum classes effectively identical in the context of binding them to python with pybind11?

```
py::enum_<options>(m, "options")
    .value("maybe", options::maybe)
    .value("yes", options::yes)
    .value("no", options::no);

py::enum_<words>(m, "words")
    .value("hello", words::hello)
    .value("world", words::world)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#enumerations-and-internal-types), it appears that the only difference is:

> The `enum_::export_values()` function exports the enum entries into the parent scope, which should be skipped for newer C++11-style strongly typed enums.

So by *not* calling `export_values`, Python will require the enum name as part of the scope when specifying values, which is conceptually closer to `enum class` than `enum`.

Worth noting that Python's `Enum` doesn't allow implicit `int` conversions like C++'s `enum`.  For that you need [`IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) - but I'm not sure if you can create `IntEnum`s from pybind.

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems to me that their docs do not mention `enum class` at all. Their unit tests, however, do include enum class: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_enum.cpp#L22

Comment: They don't use the term `enum class` directly.  But they do talk about "newer C++11-style strongly typed enums."